# How to convert the date format according systems(Windows) format through JAVA or SQL query?

Tags: sql

How to convert the date format according systems(Windows) format through JAVA or SQL query?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) maybe? Or the more "modern" sibling, [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Answer (score 0):

in sql server you can use GETDATE() function
(server date)
example query:

```
 select getdate()
```

other example, run this in sql-server Query:

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME()  
    ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()  
    ,SYSUTCDATETIME()  
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
    ,GETDATE()  
    ,GETUTCDATE();
```

and Convert date-getting current system date:

```
   SELECT CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIME())  
       ,CONVERT (time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)  
       ,CONVERT (time, GETDATE());
```

for use convert date... better than this use Microsoft help in below link

[Microsoft Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)!

Comment: How do you know Miten uses SQL Server?